# Common Lisp: Launch subprocess with different working directory than lisp process

Tags: python, bash, common-lisp, dos, ccl

Suppose I have a directory A, and subdirectory B. I cd into A and launch lisp. In that lisp process, I would like to launch a Python subprocess where Python sees B as its current working directory. The lisp process needs to have cwd in A, and the python process should have cwd in B. How do I do this in a cross-platform, simple way?

I'm looking for a solution that works with CCL and SBCL (probably using 'run-program function), and works for Windows, Linux, and OS X.

I looked at the CCL run-program documentation, and I didn't see a way to change the cwd of the launched process.

I looked at Python command-line arguments, and I didn't see one that would change the cwd of the python process.

I thought about a run-program call for 'cd B; python ...', but I'm not sure how that would work, since it's really running two programs; cd, and then python.

The Python code is being provided as input (as a file), so I cannot change any of that code (by adding an os.chdir() call or similar).

A python wrapper file that launches the python input file as a subprocess isn't ideal, because I'm sending stdin and listening to stdout of the python process launched by lisp. Adding another subprocess in between lisp and the python process that evals the input file means I'd need to do a lot of stout/stdin relaying, and I have a feeling that this would be brittle.

krzysz00's approach worked very well. Since the directory change is handled in lisp, before the python process is launched, this approach will work for launching other processes in different subdirectories (not just python).

For documentation, here's my code using krzsz00's approach that worked for SBCL & CCL. Note that it uses Hoyte's defmacro! macro, from [Let Over Lambda](http://letoverlambda.com), to easily avoid unwanted variable capture:

```
#+:SBCL
(defun cwd (dir)
  (sb-posix:chdir dir))

(defun getcwd ()
  #+SBCL (sb-unix:posix-getcwd)
  #+CCL (current-directory))

(defmacro! with-cwd (dir &body body)
  `(let ((,g!cwd (getcwd)))
     (unwind-protect (progn
                       (cwd ,dir)
                       ,@body)
     (cwd ,g!cwd))))
```

Usage:

```
(with-cwd "./B"
  (run-program ...))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run external programs (like your python process portably) see [external-program](http://common-lisp.net/project/external-program/). To change the current working directory, use this slightly modified (public domain) function `cwd` from the file http://files.b9.com/lboot/utils.lisp, which is reproduced below.

```
(defun cwd (&optional dir)
  "Change directory and set default pathname"
  (cond
   ((not (null dir))
    (when (and (typep dir 'logical-pathname)
           (translate-logical-pathname dir))
      (setq dir (translate-logical-pathname dir)))
    (when (stringp dir)
      (setq dir (parse-namestring dir)))
    #+allegro (excl:chdir dir)
    #+clisp (#+lisp=cl ext:cd #-lisp=cl lisp:cd dir)
    #+(or cmu scl) (setf (ext:default-directory) dir)
    #+cormanlisp (ccl:set-current-directory dir)
    #+(and mcl (not openmcl)) (ccl:set-mac-default-directory dir)
    #+openmcl (ccl:cwd dir)
    #+gcl (si:chdir dir)
    #+lispworks (hcl:change-directory dir)
    #+sbcl (sb-posix:chdir dir)
    (setq cl:*default-pathname-defaults* dir))
   (t
    (let ((dir
       #+allegro (excl:current-directory)
       #+clisp (#+lisp=cl ext:default-directory #-lisp=cl lisp:default-directory)
       #+(or cmu scl) (ext:default-directory)
       #+sbcl (sb-unix:posix-getcwd/)
       #+cormanlisp (ccl:get-current-directory)
       #+lispworks (hcl:get-working-directory)
       #+mcl (ccl:mac-default-directory)
       #-(or allegro clisp cmu scl cormanlisp mcl sbcl lispworks) (truename ".")))
      (when (stringp dir)
    (setq dir (parse-namestring dir)))
      dir))))
```

Combining these two functions, the code you want is:

```
(cwd #p"../b/")
(external-program:start "python" '("file.py") :output *pythins-stdout-stream* :input *pythons-stdin-stream*)
(cwd #p"../a/")
```

This will `cd` to B, run the python process as if by `python file.py &`, send the python process's stdin/stdout to the specified streams (look at the `external-program` documentation for more details), and finally execute another `cwd` that returns the lisp process to A. If the lisp process should wait until the python process is finished, use `external-program:run` instead of `external-program:start`.

Comment: Nice suggestions; thanks; I didn't use the external-program compatibility layer b/c I only need it for sbcl and ccl, the run-program for those are basically identical, and I can't easily load up packages for this code, b/c it's not being used server side.

Comment: Are there any implications here for multi-threaded programs, or is `cwd` changed on a per-thread basis?

Comment: I think `cwd` is per-thread from my quick skim of `thread_safety(5)`, but I'm not entirely certain. See if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing krzysz00's suggestion up into a package that can be found [here](https://github.com/Inaimathi/cl-cwd).

Then someone pointed out that [UIOP](http://common-lisp.net/gitweb?p=projects/asdf/asdf.git;a=blob;f=uiop/README) comes with `getcwd` and `chdir`. If you have a fairly recent lisp, UIOP should come included with your edition of [`asdf`](http://www.cliki.net/asdf).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what lisp is but could this work?

```
  import subprocess
  subprocess.Popen('python myscript.py', cwd='B')
```

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: I added an additional constraint. Inserting a python wrapper process in between the lisp and final python process isn't ideal; but maybe I could launch a python process which loads a python wrapper file; that file will cd, then load the python input file?

Comment: I have to say, this is a very awkward problem. http://cybertiggyr.com/gene/pathnames-0/node11.html

Comment: @Epic_orange: Thank goodness someone's written the portability layer.

Comment: the question was asking about doing it in common lisp